# Dataset shows only 5 event tables after re-linking Firebase with another Google Analytics account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Recently unlinked and re-linked a Firebase project with a different Google Analytics account.
The BigQuery integration configured to export GA data created the new dataset and data started populating into that.

The old dataset corresponding to the unlinked, "default" GA account, which contained ~2 years of data is still accessible in the BigQuery UI, however only the 5 most recent `event_` tables are visible in the dataset. (5 days worth of event data)

Is it possible to extract historical data from the old, unlinked dataset?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by saying that your old unlinked dataset has ~2 years of data that's still accessible, but later you are saying that only the 5 most recent `event_` tables (days) are visible in the dataset.
It's your issue that you can't query data within those ~2 years, but you can from the last 5 days?
Or is it something else, maybe the UI is not displaying properly the details of your table?
Please provide more details and if possible some screenshots/queries, please blur confidential data and point out the current behavior vs the expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry for the confusion. I meant that after unlinking the default GA account for Firebase, that we had been using for about 2 years, the corresponding dataset shows only the 5 most recent days up to the date of unlinking. 
The sum of the size of visible `event_` tables are 5.73GB, whereas `SELECT SUM(size_bytes) AS bytes FROM analytics_olddataset.__TABLES__` returns ~11.8GB for the whole dataset. Now unfortunately this leads me to think that there's nowhere near 2 years worth of data in the dataset. The default table expiry was set to "Never expire".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I could suggest, it's to do some queries for further validate the data that you have within your BigQuery dataset.

In this case, I would start by getting the dates for each table to see the amount (days) of data contained on the dataset.

```
SELECT event_date 
FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_*` 
GROUP BY event_date ORDER BY event_date
```

---

**EDIT**

A better way to do this, and get all the tables within the dataset, is using the `bq` command line [tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-command-line), see reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls).

```
bq ls firebase-public-project:analytics_153293282
```

You'll get something like this:

[image: bq ls project_id:dataset_id]

---

You could also do a `COUNT(event_date)`, so you can see how many records you have per day, and compare this to the content that you have or you can see on your Firebase project.

```
SELECT event_date, COUNT(event_date) ...
```

On the case that there's data missing, you could use [table decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators), to try to recover that data, see example [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot-examples).

About the table's expiration date you can see [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time), in short, expiration time can be set by default at dataset level and it would be applied for new tables (existing tables require a manual update of their expiration time one by one), and expiration time can be set during the creation of the table. To see if there was any change on the expiration time you could look into your logs for `protoPayload.methodName="tableservice.update"`, and see if there was set an `expireTime` as follows:

```
tableUpdateRequest: {
    resource: {
     expireTime: "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z"
     ...
    }
}
```

Besides this, if you have a GCP [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support#support-plans), you could reach them looking for further assistance on what could have happened with your tables on that dataset. Otherwise, you could open an [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Keep in mind that Firebase doesn't delete your data when [unlinking](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#unlink) a Firebase project from BigQuery, so in theory the data should be there.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Unfortunately I was not able to even find the deleted `events_` tables, so I went over to the GCP activity log and found suspicious jobs of a Google Play service account dropping tables. https://imgur.com/a/5oaIqGN